# Time complexity of nested for loop with multiple if statements

Tags: time-complexity

What will be the ideal time complexity in such a situation?

```
For i in list1:

   If i in list2:

      If i not in list3:

         i.append(list)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

The time complexity depends on the implementation your data structures list1-3 and their content. Assuming you have a list that the you need to traverse completely to execute the `x in list` statements:

```
For i in list1: // O(n) where n is the length of list1
    If i in list2: // O(n*m) where m is the length of list2
        If i not in list3 // O(n*m*o) where o is the length of list3
```

Worst case any `i in list2` is true will result in `O(n*m*o)` independent if i is on list3 or not, because you have to check the complete list3 in any way and the additional of the depending If is constant.

Best case any `i in list2` is false will result in `O(n*m)` as you don't have to execute any code of the list3 iteration.